# WCF IIS Hosted Service Slow while starting up

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, iis, startup

I have a WCF Service Hosted in IIS. After an iisreset, when I sent the first request, the service takes 4-5 minutes to return a response. Unfortunately, this startup time (even if its one time) is not acceptable to me. Most of the time taken is inside the ServiceHost constructor.
I tried analysing the actual methods taking time using YourKit. It turns out some of the internal CLR methods are taking time. I have overriden ServiceHostFactory and have some custom code which I call AFTER calling ServiceHost constructor.

I have attached output from YourKit. The first column is the method name, followed by time taken.

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type, Uri[])  143125  14
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection) 143078  15
System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary<String,System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription>&) 143062  16
System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type, Type) 143000  17
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type, Type, Object)    143000  18
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.AddBehaviors(ContractDescription, Type, Boolean, TypeLoader/ContractReflectionInfo)  142546  19
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.ApplyServiceInheritance<IBehavior,TBehaviorCollection>(Type, TBehaviorCollection, TypeLoader/ServiceInheritanceCallback<IBehavior,TBehaviorCollection>)  142531  20
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.AddBehaviorsAtOneScope<IBehavior,TBehaviorCollection>(Type, TBehaviorCollection, TypeLoader/ServiceInheritanceCallback<IBehavior,TBehaviorCollection>)   142531  21
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader/c__DisplayClass23_0.<AddBehaviors>b__0(Type, KeyedByTypeCollection<System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior>)  142531  22
System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.GetIOperationBehaviorAttributesFromType(OperationDescription, Type, Type)    142515  23
System.RuntimeType.GetInterfaceMap(Type)    142296  24
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeType, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal)  97375   25
System.RuntimeType/RuntimeTypeCache/MemberInfoCache.AddMethod(RuntimeType, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal, RuntimeType/RuntimeTypeCache/CacheType) 95921   26
System.RuntimeType/RuntimeTypeCache/MemberInfoCache.Insert(T[]&, String, RuntimeType/MemberListType)    93812   27
System.RuntimeType/RuntimeTypeCache/MemberInfoCache.MergeWithGlobalList(T[])    77625   28
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CacheEquals(Object) 7734    29
```

What is taking time here? Is there anything I can do to improve this?

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you, because we cannot see your code. Please add the relevant code to your question. A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: What is shown here is just over 2 minutes. That is still long but not the 4-5 minutes you claim it takes. If you strip out services one by one, which services takes the longest to initialize? Share how that one is structured (in number and type of operations, hierarchy). Which behaviors are used by the services? Any certficates involved? Is there any outgoing network traffic at startup? If yes, which?